# How to "if: page can scroll down"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've been trying to create a condition that would only appear if the page can be scrolled down but I can't find a way to condition if the page is "full" enough that it scrolls down. Not even sure if its possible to do so.

I'm doing this to add a "scroll to top" link on my pages, but only if there is a need to scroll

If anybody can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: why not use JavaScript to show the "scroll to top" link if the page *has been scrolled*?

Comment: You might compare height of the including container against viewport height. If the first is larger => scroll is needed/possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a show the 'scroll to top' link only if the page has been scrolled using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 25 ){
        $('#scroll_to_top').show();
    }else{
        $('#scroll_to_top').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jquery, so can I ask you if I can replace the '#scroll_to_top' by the code for an image with a link?

Comment: The `#something` notation in jQuery refers to an HTML entity with that ID: `<x id="something"></x>`.